# Location of O2 sensor on '97 Geo Metro

Tags: o2-sensor, geo

Where is the O2 sensor located on a 97 Geo Metro (4 cylinder)? I have looked at the whole exhaust system. The check engine light is on, and the code indicates that the sensor is defective. I'd like to change the sensor to see if the light goes out.

Comment: Which sensor? There are two of them. Can you give us the exact code?

Answer (score 1):

Which sensor does the code say is bad?

You should have 2 oxygen sensors, one before the catalytic convertor and one after.

Be sure to check everywhere from the exhaust manifold to the muffler. I don't specifically where the o2 sensor are in your model, but check the cat itself as well.